# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "dish" does not exist

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, heroku, heroku-postgres

I created java(spring) app on heroku, connected postgresql to it. When I make request on app, log shows

> WARN 4 --- [io-14883-exec-3] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42P01
>   app[web.1]: 2016-12-11 12:13:09.942 ERROR 4 --- [io-14883-exec-3] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: relation "dish" does not exist
>   app[web.1]:   Position: 13
>   app[web.1]: 2016-12-11 12:13:10.031 ERROR 4 --- [io-14883-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement] with root cause
>   app[web.1]: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: **ERROR: relation "dish" does not exist**
>   app[web.1]:   Position: 13

application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=${JDBC_DATABASE_URL}
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.maxActive=10
spring.datasource.maxIdle=5
spring.datasource.minIdle=2
spring.datasource.initialSize=5
spring.datasource.removeAbandoned=true
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=false
#spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

***This model works on my local machine***

Model:

```
@Entity
public class Dish
  implements Serializable
{
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long dishId;
  private Long categoryId;
  private String name;
  private String description;
  private Float price;
  private String picUrl;

  public Long getId()
  {
    return this.dishId;
  }

  public void setId(Long dishId)
  {
    this.dishId = dishId;
  }

  public Long getCategoryId()
  {
    return this.categoryId;
  }

  public void setCategoryId(Long categoryId)
  {
    this.categoryId = categoryId;
  }

  public String getName()
  {
    return this.name;
  }

  public void setName(String name)
  {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public String getDescription()
  {
    return this.description;
  }

  public void setDescription(String description)
  {
    this.description = description;
  }

  public Float getPrice()
  {
    return this.price;
  }

  public void setPrice(Float price)
  {
    this.price = price;
  }

  public String getPicUrl()
  {
    return this.picUrl;
  }

  public void setPicUrl(String picUrl)
  {
    this.picUrl = picUrl;
  }
}
```

Comment: So there's no table named dish. Where's the problem here?

Comment: @CraigRinger  MR CAP)) I know that, My question is WHY? I did enitity which wokr on my local machine but doest on heroku

Answer (score 2):

```
#spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

is commented out. So Hibernate won't create your tables. Which is why they don't exist.